# In mathematical optimization , are Sequential Quadratic Programming and Sequential Least SQuares Programming the same thing?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The Sequential Quadratic Programming that I am talking about is based on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming). And the Sequential Least SQuares Programming is based on [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#id17)

Answer (score 0):

Given the information available it seems they are not identical. Based on the SciPy documentationp provided,the Sequential Least Squares programming does not require the objective function to be twice differentiable. However, the Sequential Quadratic Programming wiki-page does require the objective function and the constraints to be twice differentiable. Given these differences they are not the same thing, although it's possible under certain conditions they are. If one wants to know when they might be the same thing I would wager it is when the objective function and constraints are twice continuously differentiable.